# one way ANOVA with repeated measurements - Not within-subjects

Tags: statistics

I'm trying to conduct a one-way ANOVA with repeated measurements; however, the repeated measurements are independent, they do not represent a measurement of a subject under different conditions, but simply a replication of the same conditions. This means if I obtain two measurements, for example, for one subject and they are different, it's only due to randomness.

I looked around and there seems to be a within-subjects ANOVA, but that assumes that the measurements per subject are correlated, which is not the case I have.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Though the measurements are under the same conditions, I think it would still be wise to treat the data as repeated measures. Do you believe the measurements of one subject are the same as you'd expect to see if the measurements were from unique individuals? Often there is some correlation of those measurements purely because they all came from the same subject. If there isn't significance, at least you've covered your bases.

Answer (score 1):

If your repeated measurements are truly independent, then you can just treat them as replicates and conduct the usual one-way ANOVA.