# How can I perform a 2-way repeated measures anova using statsmodels?

Tags: python, statistics, statsmodels

I found [this](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/examples/generated/example_interactions.html) example, which explains how to perform a 2-way ANOVA.  I was wondering how to do the same for a repeated-measures design.

I did see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15210108/one-way-anova-with-repeated-measurements-not-within-subjects?rq=1), but I cannot assume independence of my repeated measurements.

I'm using statsmodels version `0.5.0.dev-Unknown`.

Ideally, I'd like to use statsmodels, but if there's a viable solution using another library, I'd be interested in  hearing about it as well.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing built-in yet for repeated measures designs ANOVA, though I suspect it wouldn't be difficult to support. If you could provide or point me to an example and file an [enhancement request](https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues) we will look to support it.

Comment: I saw that you opened an issue on the github tracker.  I'm afraid I can't release any of the data I'm working with (human subject data has pretty strict privacy rules), but [here](http://www.mrc-cbu.cam.ac.uk/people/rik.henson/personal/repanova.m) is the Matlab function I've been using thus far in case it helps demonstrate my intent.  Essentially, I have two factors (both have three levels) and one measure.

Answer (score 1):

> There is nothing built-in yet for repeated measures designs ANOVA, though I suspect it wouldn't be difficult to support. If you could provide or point me to an example and file an enhancement request we will look to support it.

Here ya go...

https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/1863